# When parents apply for UK visas, can one be approved and one refused?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, family

For people who apply together for a UK visitor visa as parents, or parents and one child, can it be the case that one visa gets approved and the other rejected? Or is it a required that all should be approved ***or*** all rejected?

Answer (score 8):

Yes the result can be different for different applicants even if they apply together.

[Here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109423/uk-visa-for-my-child-refused-as-eco-could-not-be-satisfied-that-their-welfare-wo) is one such example.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, for example, a big question is always: "Will this person return to their home country once their permission to stay in the UK runs out". If Mr. X applies, they might say "Mr. X is married to Mrs. X, so he will surely return home to her". If Mr. X and Mrs. X both apply, that reason to return home has disappeared. So it's quite possible that each of them individually would get a visa, but not both together.

Answer (score 2):

Both applications had the same result, as both were approved. The wife's application was dependent on the husband's application, so maybe that's way the result was the same.

Comment: It is normal for a dependant applicant to be approved if the primary is approved. But you asked if it was possible otherwise hence the other answers. Congrats!